# How to display corresponding tag on hover for a div

Tags: html, css, text, hover, toggle

Hi i have a circular div and i want some text to show up on hover and disappear on mouse out using only css
for example if have a circular div , i want the tag say home to appear on its right side on hover and disappear on mouse out

my code for the buttons is-

```
 .cbp-fbscroller > nav a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    color: transparent;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 25px 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.no-touch .cbp-fbscroller > nav a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

.cbp-fbscroller > nav a.cbp-fbcurrent {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You can use `:before` and `:after` to achieve something like this in CSS..

Comment: Please show your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.....

```
.circle {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 5px solid whitesmoke;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 background:url('http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-  bg_flat_100_555_40x100.png');
 }
.circle:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
 background: whitesmoke;
 border-radius: 50%;
 content:"";
 display: block;
  }
 .circle:hover span {
 display:inline;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left:100%;
 margin: -5px 0px -5px -25%;
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 25%;
}
span
{
display:none;
}
```

For Demo:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/duhUS/1/)